# Setting HTMLMediaElement.playbackRate from Blazor without javascript interop

Tags: javascript, video, blazor, interop, playback-rate

I'd like to understand if there is a way of setting value of HTMLMediaElement properties `playbackRate`
from Blazor WebAssembly without resorting to javascript interoperability (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playbackRate).

Since Blazor cannot access DOM elements directly (and it is not meant to do it), I think the answer is no and I need to use javascript interoperability. Howerver I'm not much of an expert, so I'm asking.

I know there are projects helping in managing videos in Blazor, like [Vidazor](https://github.com/AradAral/Vidazor), but in the end they use javascript interop too, and I'd like to avoid that as much as possible.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, JavaScript Interop is required here.

At the moment, `HTMLElement` (and inheriting types, including `HTMLMediaElement`) properties that cannot be set via attributes (i.e. where updating the markup is possible) require JavaScript, [regardless of your tech stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Concepts#:%7E:text=By%20itself%2C%20WebAssembly%20cannot%20currently%20directly%20access%20the%20DOM%3B%20it%20can%20only%20call%20JavaScript%2C%20passing%20in%20integer%20and%20floating%20point%20primitive%20data%20types.). Even if .NET came with a fuller DOM API, it would still require JS interop under the hood.

Note: for Blazor WebAssembly (and other WASM technologies), [this might eventually be possible, directly](https://github.com/WebAssembly/gc/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Thanks, let's hope this feature will be added.